# Replacing userform name with variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following function put in "Module1" determine the maximum value of a text box in user form, named "frmAddRecord2", that can be input.

txtLV and txtMaxLV are textboxes under "frmAddRecord2".

And txtMaxLV_Pass is a boolean variable put under frmAddRecord2 as well. At this stage, this function works fine.

```
Public Function txtLV_Max() As Long

    With frmAddRecord2
        If .txtLV.Value >= 99 Or Not .txtMaxLV_Pass Then
            txtLV_Max = 109
        Else
            txtLV_Max = .txtMaxLV.Value - 1
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

As I will have "frmAddRecord1", "frmAddRecord2", "frmAddRecord3" ... etc, so I would like to call the following sub when frmAddRecord1 or frmAddRecord2 
 is activated.

```
Public Sub SetActiveUserForm(Optional UserFormName As String)

    If UserFormName = "frmAddRecord1" Then
        Set ActiveUserForm = frmAddRecord1
        UserFormShown = True
    ElseIf UserFormName = "frmAddRecord2" Then
        Set ActiveUserForm = frmAddRecord2
        UserFormShown = True
    Else
        Set ActiveUserForm = Nothing
        UserFormShown = False
    End If

End Sub
```

And I would like to restructure the function as:

```
Public Function txtLV_Max() As Long

    With activeuserform
        If .txtLV.Value >= 99 Or Not .txtMaxLV_Pass Then
            txtLV_Max = 109
        Else
            txtLV_Max = .txtMaxLV.Value - 1
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

However, error occur at the Line "If .txtLV.Value >= 99 Or Not ***.txtMaxLV_Pass*** Then" . After testing, the txtMaxLV_Pass is found failed to be call after I restructured the function. And it work fine again if I moved txtMaxLV_Pass to be public under Module1.

But I would like to ask, if I want to keep the txtMaxLV_Pass under the userform, what should I changed in declare the userform variable. Please advice, I have studied this in web site and books, but still not able to tackle. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Do you have `option explicit` at the top of your code modules? Is `ActiveUserForm` a global variable you're referencing?

Comment: Yes, I put option explicit at the top of module1 and frmAddRecord2. ActiveUserForm is global variable in module1; txtMaxLv is a global variable in frmAddRecord2. And while the function is using, the userform is still showing on the screen.

Comment: What type of variable do you have `ActiveUserForm` as? I think it may need to be `Variant` for the userform properties to be accessible.

Comment: I set ActiveUserForm as userform

Comment: Try changing `Dim ActiveUserForm as Userform` to `Dim ActiveUserForm as Object`.

Comment: Mistella, Thank you very much for your guidance, after you remind me about "varient", I have tried when I go back home after work. And it really works. However, I am curious why "userform" is not the key to the type. So I go a step further to find out the reason. And in a website I learnt a new function "typename()", to check frmAddRecord2, and it returns me frmAddRecord2 as well. I finally understand it is a class. I think this is a very good learningexperience to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to learn more from this experience. I added the information as an answer, so if someone else has a similar issue, they won't have to dig through the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Global variable `ActiveUserForm` was given the type of `Userform`. However, to access UserForm properties from a Userform variable, it actually needs to be of type `Object` or `Variant`.